# Calling Dispose method inside constructor which throws an exception or behaves unexpectedly

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a class which consumes some unmanaged resources and I would like to free them deterministically and request that the finalizer not be called for the object at hand. My `Dispose()` method of the class accomplishes this.

In the event of an exception being thrown or something otherwise going wrong or behaving unexpectedly in the constructor, I would like to call `Dispose()` before throwing. However, I rarely come across implementations which catch thrown exceptions or handle an error in the constructor of disposable objects and then invoke `Dispose()` on the object - In a lot of cases the author leaves the cleanup to the finalizer. I have not read anything which states that calling `Dispose()` in a failed constructor is bad practice, but while looking through the .NET source code I have yet to come across such exception or error handling in a disposable object constructor.

Can I call `Dispose()` inside a "failed" constructor and still be considered a good coding citizen?

**Edit to clarify** - I am talking about inside the constructor:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
     private IntPtr _libPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

     public MyClass(string dllPath)
     {
         _libPtr = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(dllPath);

         if (_libPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
         { 
             IntPtr fxnPtr = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(_libPtr, "MyFunction");
             if (fxnPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
             {
                 Dispose(); // Cleanup resources - NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(_libPtr);
                 throw new NullReferenceException("Error linking library."); 
             }
         }
         else
         {
             throw new DllNotFoundException("Something helpful");
         }
     } 

     // ...
}
```

Comment: Note that if an exception is thrown in a constructor, the constructor does not return normally, so the constructed object is never passed back, so it's impossible for the client code to call Dispose on it.

Comment: Yes, but I am talking about within the constructor itself.

Comment: Do you mean to try catch in the constructor and call dispose in the catch handler?

Comment: Oops, I misread a paragraph. Apologies. FWIW I don't see anything wrong with your approach. I would rethrow the exception after Disposing, of course.

Comment: @Blorgbeard - Yes, I am talking about handling in the constructor.

Comment: @closers - this is _not_ opinion based. Don't be silly.

Comment: .NET programmers tend to have trouble accepting that disposal is optional.  Only dispose when it is useful.  It just isn't very useful in this case, the object will always be collected on the next gen #0 collection and finalized soon after that.  A couple of hundred milliseconds, give or take.

Comment: @HansPassant: Do you believe that worrying about unncessary objects in the finalization queue is total over optimization and downright looney at this point in .NET? Would you advocate just implementing a finalizer which called FreeLibrary?

Comment: Just reason it out, what happens if the constructor *doesn't* throw?  You are going to keep that library loaded for a while.  Is that a leak?  What is the point of having a lean crashing program?  Does it sound looney enough yet?

Comment: Well I was never debating about throwing - I was going to catch - Dispose (which just calls FreeLibrary) - and then throw. This way the library is deterministically unloaded and the caller knows that something went wrong. Thanks for the raising the point about it really not mattering any which way as the finalizer will wrap things up in a short amount of time. I really enjoy having my ideas on something sent through the blender. :-)

Comment: @HansPassant has a point in that the object is one that is particularly likely to be cleaned up quickly and therefore particularly likely to be finalised quickly. I do though still prefer to release all unmanaged resources ASAP. If nothing else catching too many cases does no harm, not catching some does, catching as many as possible is just simpler.

Comment: I don't think that Library will unload itself. The sensible thing is to wrap it in a SafeHandle and maybe implement the managed part of the Dispose pattern on your class. You should never (have to) write a Finalizer.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Well the Finalizer for my object will run unless I explicitly suppress it from running. The only time that I suppress it is when I have already invoked a call to `FreeLibrary`. My understanding is that `FreeLibrary` just decrements the reference counter to the library - When it reaches zero then the library is unloaded. In my case, if the constructor did not do any clean up, then the Finalizer would do the clean up shortly after. For a few extra keystrokes, I release the unmanaged resource ASAP. It seems universally agreed upon to move from `IntPtr` to `SafeHandle`. Thanks.

Comment: And with the SafeHandle you can forget about writing your own ~Destructor()s. And keep your constructor clean and to the point. Much easier and reliable all around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't have an object call `Dispose` on itself, but I certainly would have a constructor clean itself up if necessary. I'd also like to make that clean-up as simple as possible Considering your example, I'd prefer to compose it something like:

```
internal sealed class Library : IDisposable
{
  IntPtr _libPtr; // Or better yet, can we use or derive from SafeHandle?
  public Library(string dllPath)
  {
     _libPtr = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(dllPath);
     if(_libPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
     {
       GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
       throw new DllNotFoundException("Library Load Failed");
     }
  }
  private void Release()
  {
    if(_libPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
      NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(_libPtr);
    _libPtr = IntPtr.Zero; // avoid double free even if a caller double-disposes.
  }
  public void Dispose()
  {
    Release();
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }
  ~Library()
  {
    Release();
  }
  public IntPtr GetProcAddress(string functionName)
  {
    if(_libPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
      throw new ObjectDisposedException();
    IntPtr funcPtr = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(_libPtr, functionName);
    if(_funcPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
      throw new Exception("Error binding function.");
    return _funcPtr;
  }
}
```

So far nice and simple. Either this object is constructed successfully and can be released by the code that called it, or it doesn't need clean-up. We can even prevent the no-op finalisation, just to be nice. The main thing is that there's nothing that needs cleaned up created after the last thing that could reasonably go wrong.

And then:

```
public sealed class MyClass : IDisposable
{
  private readonly Library _lib;
  private readonly IntPtr _funcPtr;

  public MyClass(string dllPath)
  {
    _lib = new Library(dllPath); // If this fails, we throw here, and we don't need clean-up.

    try
    { 
      _funcPtr = _libPtr.GetProcAddress("MyFunction");
    }
    catch
    {
      // To be here, _lib must be valid, but we've failed over-all.
      _lib.Dispose();
      throw;
    }
  }
  public void Dispose()
  {
    _lib.Dispose();
  }
  // No finaliser needed, because no unmanaged resources needing finalisation are directly held.
}
```

Again, I can ensure clean-up, but I don't call `this.Dispose();` While `this.Dispose()` could do the same trick, I mainly prefer to have the field I am cleaning up explicit in the same method (the constructor here) that set it but failed to do all of its job. For one thing, the only place there can be a partially-constructed object is in the constructor, so the only place I need be considering a partially-constructed object is in the constructor; I've made it an invariant of the rest of the class that `_lib` isn't null.

Let's imagine that functions had to be released separately from libraries, just to have a more complicated example. Then I would also wrap `_funcPtr` to keep with the simplifying rule; either a class has a single unmanaged resource that it cleans up through `Dispose()` and a finaliser, or it has one or more `IDisposable` fields that it cleans up through `Dispose` or it doesn't need disposal, but never a combination of the above.

```
internal sealed class Function : IDisposable
{
  IntPtr _funcPtr; // Again better yet, can we use or derive from SafeHandle?
  public Function(Lib library, string functionName)
  {
    _funcPtr = library.GetProcAddress(functionName);
    if(_funcPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
      throw new Exception("Error binding function."); 
    }
  }
  private void Release()
  {
    if(_funcPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
      NativeMethods.HypotheticalForgetProcAddressMethod(_funcPtr);
    _funcPtr = IntPtr.Zero; // avoid double free.
  }
  public void Dispose()
  {
    Release();
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }
  ~Function()
  {
    Release();
  }
}
```

And then `MyClass` would be:

```
public sealed class MyClass : IDisposable
{
  private Library _lib;
  private Function _func;

  public MyClass(string dllPath)
  {
    _lib = new Library(dllPath); // If this fails, we throw here, and we don't need clean-up.
    try
    { 
      _func = new Function(_lib, "MyFunction");
      try
      {
        SomeMethodThatCanThrowJustToComplicateThings();
      }
      catch
      {
        _func.Dispose();
        throw;
      }
    }
    catch
    {
      _lib.Dispose();
      throw;
    }
  }
  public void Dispose()
  {
    _func.Dispose();
    _lib.Dispose();
  }
}
```

This makes the constructor a bit more verbose, and I'd rather avoid two things that can go wrong affecting two things that need clean-up in the first place. It does though reflect why I like the clean-up to be explicit as to the different fields; I might want to clean up both fields, or just one, depending on where the exception hits.

Comment: The approach of making the constructor responsible for its own cleanup in case of failure may be "cleaner" than using `Dispose` for non-inherited non-inheritable classes, but I'm not sure how it could be extended to scenarios involving inheritance unless the base class defines a virtual "clean up failed constructor" method.  How would you suggest a derived class should clean up a partially-constructed base if not via `Dispose`?

Comment: @supercat generally I'd just leave it to the finaliser in that case, which I should hope was rare. I would see `base.Dispose()` as reasonable (the base shouldn't be partially-constructed at that point) unless it did the popular approach of having a virtual `Dispose(bool)` in which case it's going to call back to the derived class, and that's too painful.

Comment: What is painful about the call to the derived `Dispose(bool)` if the inheritance contract specifies that it may be invoked on partially-constructed objects?  If the derived constructor sets at least one field to a non-default value (which should generally be the case), I would think it should be easy for the `Dispose(bool)` method to simply chain to the parent method if invoked without the derived constructor having run.  I would regard the necessity of using a finalizer in a given situation as generally being evidence of an associated design defect (sometimes one for which no other fix...

Comment: ...would be practical) and would suggest that even if proper cleanup is awkward it's almost always better than "hope the finalizer can handle it" except when dealing with resources that are both fungible and plentiful.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is the pattern implemented by the C++/CLI compiler, which should have been standard in all .NET languages but is not.  The failure of .NET to specify that a failed constructor should result in a call to `Dispose` on the partially-constructed object (and that any legitimate `Dispose` implementation must be prepared to deal with this) means that many kinds of objects must either require the use of factory methods rather than constructors, require an awkward two-step construction sequence in which objects are in a weird "limbo" until the second step completes, or adopt a "hope nothing goes too badly wrong wrong" philosophy for error handling and cleanup.

Of these approaches, the best is probably to require the use of a factory method for construction.  Because factory methods are specific to the type of object being created, this approach require derived classes to include some annoying boilerplate to the effect of:

```
DerivedFoo Create(params)
{
  // Phase 1 shouldn't allocate resources yet
  Derived foo result = new DerivedFoo(params);
  // NON-VIRTUAL Phase 2 method which chains to a virtual one within try/finally
  result.Initialize();
  return result;
}
```

Not totally horrible, but irksome.  The .NET Framework could have benefited enormously from allowing classes to specify an `Initialize` method which would be invoked between the completion of the most-derived constructor and the return to client code, but since no such feature "officially" exists the best one can do is probably to kludge it manually [I think there are some kludges designed for COM inter-op that might help, but I don't know how well supported there are].